# Minion Math font `'` and `\prime` behaves differently

Tags: fonts, xetex, kerning

I am using Minion Math to typeset a book. The editor asked if it is possible to lower the position of the `'` in equations when it is used with a lowercase `p` letter.

I noticed that the behaviour of `'` and `\prime` is different if Minion Math is loaded or Latin Modern is used. `\prime` seem to be a supersuperscrpt.

With Minion Math:
[image]

With LM:
[image]

I use `XeLaTeX`, but the same issue is happening with `LuaLaTeX`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
%%% Copied from the unicode-math documentation
\setmathfont%{Minion Math}%[
[SizeFeatures = {
{Size = -6.01, Font = MinionMath-Tiny}, 
{Size = 6.01-8.41, Font = MinionMath-Capt},
{Size = 8.41-13.01, Font = MinionMath-Regular},
{Size = 13.01-19.91, Font = MinionMath-Subh},
{Size = 19.91-, Font = MinionMath-Disp}
}]%
{Minion Math}

\RequirePackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\verb+$T(p)=p'$+:\hspace{1cm}    $T(p)=p'$

\verb+$T(p)=p\prime$+:\hspace{1cm}    $T(p)=p\prime$

\verb+$T(p)=p^{\prime}$+:\hspace{1cm}    $T(p)=p^{\prime}$
\end{document}
```

**SOLUTION PROPOSED BY DAVID:**

The solution seems to work fine:

[image]

Comment: you have only shown a tiny fragment of code, are you using unicode-math or some other way to access the math font, are other superscripts too high, the superscript raise could be lowered for example. is the \prime character already superscripted in the font, eg does `p\prime` look right already, but `p^{\prime}` is too small and high?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I exprese incorrectly myself. My problem is with `'` which is what the author has used in the book. As you can see `$p'$` and `$p\prime$` aren't equivalent with Minion Math

Comment: `p'` and `p\prime` are not usually equivalent, `p'` is converted to `p^{\prime}` but in some fonts not designed for TeX the `\prime` character is already superscript in the font so you need to generate `p\prime` instead. That is clearly the case here now you have added the image.

Comment: I would expect that ``{\catcode`\'\active\gdef'{\prime}}`` would do the right thing, but I don't have the font to test

Comment: Please, never use `minimal` for examples; the class is not meant for them.

Comment: `{\catcode`\'\active\gdef'{\prime}}` seems to work when I put after `\begin{document}` but if i put inside `\AtBeginDocuument` I have the error `Missing control sequence inserted. 
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible` Any way to issue the fix but not in the main document? I ma using TL2000 and could not upgrade.

Comment: If I ask `\show\prime`, I get `\prime=\Umathchar"0"0"2032`. With STIX Two Math, the three calls result in the same output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle With this redefinition of `'`, `f'^2` should not work, right? So how then are you supposed to typeset this with fonts like Minion Math?

Comment: ``\catcode`\'\active\AtBeginDocument{\def'{\prime}}\catcode`\'=12 ``

Comment: @Gaussler well it would superscript the prime, without the font can't say how that would look  you could set up a virtual font with the prime in the expected non-superscript position.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the solution seems to work fine. I now have to check more complex equations in the book.

Comment: @TeXtnik I think you should report this to the creator of Minion Math, as LuaTeX and XeTeX are supposed to be officially supported.

Comment: @Gaussler I will contact the creator of the font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p'` and `p\prime` are not usually equivalent, `p'` is converted to `p^{\prime}` but in some fonts not designed for TeX, the `\prime` character is already superscript in the font so you need to generate `p\prime` instead.

That is clearly the case here now you have added the image.

```
\catcode`\'\active
\AtBeginDocument{\def'{\prime}}
\catcode`\'=12
```

would remove the code that makes `'` superscript itself and simply makes it work like ' works in text mode where it is an ordinary character but just has a raised position in the font.

Note that this will not wrok in the presence of large symbols. Normally `\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)'`  would place a TeX-superscript on the closing ), but here you would just get a standard ' after the ) so it is probably too low.  However ' is most commonly used with single letters not constructed expressions so this may not matter in practice.

Comment: Your `\left...\right'` explanation is confusing. Do you mean `\left(...\right)'`?

Comment: @Gaussler I'll expand it a bit (but yes)

Comment: Also, I never quite understood why everyone wants to delay active character definitions using `\AtBeginDocument`. Why not just do it immediately?

Comment: @Gaussler blame Will:-) unicode-math delays essentially everything to begin document not just active character definitions so if you want ti adjust anything unicode-math does you need to delay.

Comment: It should also be possible to make a solution that solves that last `\left...\right` problem. E.g. you could redefine `\prime`, adjusting its size and vertical position. Then the “old” definition of `'` would work as usual. In fact, I think this solution would be preferable.

Comment: Why do you set `\catcode`\'=12` after the redefinition of `'`? If the character is no longer active, whatever you redefined it to should no longer matter, should it?

Comment: @Gaussler you don't want it to be active in the document, just define its active definition it is mathcode"8000 so the active defintion gets used. (been that way since the beginning of plain tex)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127172/discussion-between-gaussler-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 2):

Do not use "SizeFeatures", everything shows prefectly.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Minion Math}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\verb+$T(p)=p'-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)'$+:\hspace{1cm}    $T(p)=p'-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)'$
\verb+$T(p)=p\prime-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\prime$+:\hspace{1cm}    $T(p)=p\prime-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\prime$
\verb+$T(p)=p^{\prime}-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\prime}$+:\hspace{1cm}    $T(p)=p^{\prime}-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\prime}$
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

When `SizeFeatures` is changed to:

```
\setmathfont{Minion Math}[SizeFeatures={
  {Size=-6.01,Font=MinionMath-Tiny,Style=MathScriptScript},
  {Size=6.01-8.41,Font=MinionMath-Capt,Style=MathScript},
  {Size=8.41-13.01,Font=MinionMath-Regular},
  {Size=13.01-19.91,Font=MinionMath-Subh},
  {Size=19.91-,Font=MinionMath-Disp}}
]
```

with the `Style` feature added, it works correctly.

Comment: Could you expand this into a complete example so that we can see what you're talking about?  I'm having trouble understanding how your code is different than the original.